# Calling function another time throws segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I ended up with a very strange bug in C.
I have some structures defined like this:

```
typedef struct TrapAttribute {
    char name[16];
    uint8_t type;
} TrapAttribute;

typedef struct TrapBlockType {
    uint16_t id;
    char name[16];
    
    SDL_Texture **textures;
    uint8_t texturesCount;
    TrapAttribute **attributes;
    uint8_t attributesCount;
} TrapBlockType;
```

and I manipulate `TrapBlockType` objects through `TrapBlockType *` pointers. I need to free the memory I used at the end of my code:

```
void TrapFreeAttributesList(TrapBlockType *type, uint8_t count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        free(type->attributes[i]);
    }
    free(type->attributes);
}

void TrapFreeTexturesList(TrapBlockType *type, uint8_t count); //No need for the full code in this question

void TrapFreeBlockType(TrapBlockType *type){
    TrapFreeAttributesList(type, type->attributesCount);
    TrapFreeTexturesList(type, type->texturesCount);
    free(type);
}
```

I have two `TrapBlockTypes *` structures, and freeing the first one causes no problem while freeing the second one causes segmentation fault:

```
TrapBlockType **list; //I don't show the full code, but this list contains two TrapBlockType *
TrapFreeBlockType(list[0]);
printf("Block type number 0 successfully freed\n");
TrapFreeBlockType(list[1]); //Segmentation fault occurs here
printf("Block type number 1 successfully freed\n");
```

After some tests, it looks like the problem comes from the `for` loop in `TrapFreeAttributesList`:

```
void TrapFreeAttributesList(TrapBlockType *type, uint8_t count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){ //Code stops here with segmentation fault on the second call
        free(type->attributes[i]);
    }
    free(type->attributes);
}
```

(I tried to copy-paste the code of `TrapFreeAttributesList` in `TrapFreeBlockType` instead of calling it, but it didn't change anything)

But why on earth does this error occur on the second call and not the first one? Why do I get segmentation fault in the first place?

Comment: The problem is most likely in the part you didn't show. Try to make a [mcve]. Also learn how to use you debugger, that would be the right tool for finding this kind of problems.

Comment: I'm working on a reproductible example, and I'll try a debugger next time, thank you :)

Comment: Why do you pass the `count` parameter to the function if you already pass a pointer to the whole struct?

Comment: How do you initialized and populate those pointers?

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have a ```count``` argument, I'm changing that right now (though it doesn't actually change the problem)… Those pointers are initialized through functions that modify the list (declared as a global variable). There is no explicit variable except for the list of block types, everything is initialized through expressions

Comment: I have trouble creating a minimal reproductible example, because I still get segmentation fault but not at the same point…

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my bug (with lots of help :)). The problem was indeed in a part I didn't show: in the function that adds a block type to the list, I accidentally freed everything due to an error.

The array is dynamically allocated, so I have to extend it when there is not enough room for a new block type. And I made a mistake writing this part.
Here is some explanation:

```
//"count" is the number of elements in the list. "listsize" is the size of the list
if (count == listsize){
    TrapBlockType **tmp = realloc(blockTypes, listsize*2*(sizeof(TrapBlockType *)));
    if (tmp == NULL){
        perror("Realloc error while extending types list");
        return -1;
    }
    
    blockTypes = tmp;
    free(tmp)//Error! This frees the whole list accidentally. I though I
            //would need to free it to avoid memory leak, but I actually don't: it's a simple pointer, not a memory zone.
    listsize *= 2;
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to start removing from the end.

Try this, see if it is working

```
TrapBlockType **list; 
TrapFreeBlockType(list[1]);
printf("Block type number 1 successfully freed\n");
TrapFreeBlockType(list[0]); 
printf("Block type number 0 successfully freed\n");
```

Comment: I just tried, and it didn't work as well :sob:. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).